# Data from a Python script to URL as JSON

Tags: python, json, function, post, urllib

I've spent a lot of time on this but still can't seem to get it to work. The task is - I have to send system stats to a URL and the script is supposed to pull it, convert the namedtuple of each cpu stats of a machine and then send them all in 1 single POST request as JSON. The connection must close once the data has been sent.

For the '1 single POST request' functionality, I added the latter function (senddata_to_server) in the script. Without it (with the connection details simply listed there without a function)  , when I ran it on Mac/Windows/Linux, it used to return all the namedtuples 1 by 1 and then a '200 OK' and then go on printing 'Connection refused' forever. Now when I run it, it just hangs there without returning anything.

(I have asked this question earlier (  [HTTP Post request with Python JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754405/http-post-request-with-python-json)  ) but I need to have the 'params' inside the loop and the connection details outside it.

```
import psutil 
import socket
import time
import sample
import json
import httplib
import urllib

serverHost = sample.host
port = sample.port

thisClient = socket.gethostname()
currentTime = int(time.time())
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((serverHost, port))
cpuStats = psutil.cpu_times_percent(percpu=True)



def loop_thru_cpus():
    while True:
        global cpuStats

        cpuStats = "/n".join([json.dumps(stats._asdict()) for stats in cpuStats])

        try:

            command = 'put cpu.usr ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[0]) + "host ="+thisClient+ "/n"
            s.sendall(command)
            command = 'put cpu.nice ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[1]) + "host ="+ thisClient+ "/n"
            s.sendall(command)
            command = 'put cpu.sys ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[2]) + "host ="+ thisClient+ "/n"
            s.sendall(command)
            command = 'put cpu.idle ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[3]) + "host ="+ thisClient+ "/n"
            s.sendall(command)
            params = urllib.urlencode({'cpuStats': cpuStats, 'deviceKey': 1234, 'timeStamp': str(currentTime)})
            return params
            print cpuStats

        except IndexError:
            continue
        except socket.error:
            print "Connection refused"
            continue

        finally:
            s.close()


def senddata_to_server():
    x = loop_thru_cpus()
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverHost, port)
    conn.request = ("POST", "", x.params, headers)
    response = conn.response()
    print response.status, response. reason
    print x.cpuStats
    conn.close()
loop_thru_cpus()
senddata_to_server()
```

Comment: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: I may be dense, but I can't see a question here. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Robᵩ - I have to use only the built-in libraries and so, can't use 'requests'. I should have clarified - Given the task and the code/logic here, what am I doing wrong? Even pointers would help. For some reason the list comprehension line now raises the error - `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_asdict`, whether I keep it there or put it inside the 'try:' block.

Answer (score 0):

> > Given the task and the code/logic here, what am I doing wrong?

I can't quite tell what your task is, but here are some things you may be doing wrong:

- You are connecting to the server directly (via `socket.connect()`) and through the framework (via `HTTPlib.connect()`)
- You misspelled newline: it should be `'\n'`, not `'/n'`
- You have a while loop that can only execute once (because you `return` in the middle of it).
- You have a print statement after your return statement
- You are sending malformed `put` commands to the web server
- You call `loop_thru_cpus()` twice
- You set the content-type incorrectly to `application/json` -- you aren't sending well-formed json.
- You aren't sending a url to `HTTPlib.HTTPConnection.request()` (may be allowed in practice, disallowed in the documentation)
- You aren't invoking `conn.request()` correctly -- get rid of `=`
- In [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) it says to call `conn.getresponse()`, not `conn.response()`

Here is a program that hopefully does what you ask for:

```
import psutil 
import socket
import time
import json
import httplib
import urllib

# httpbin provides an echo service at http://httpbin.org/post
serverHost = 'httpbin.org'
port = 80
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

# My psutil only has cpu_times, not cpu_times_percent
cpuStats = psutil.cpu_times(percpu=True)

# Convert each namedTuple to a json string
cpuStats = [json.dumps(stats._asdict()) for stats in cpuStats]

# Convert each json string to the form required by the assignment
cpuStats = [urllib.urlencode({'cpuStats':stats, 'deviceKey':1234}) for stats in cpuStats]

# Join stats together, one per line
cpuStats = '\n'.join(cpuStats)

# Send the data ...

# connect
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverHost, port)

# Send the data
conn.request("POST", url, cpuStats)

# Check the response, should be 200
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason

# httpbin.org provides an echo service -- what did we send?
print response.read()

conn.close()
```